# Best way to load images in a Adapter

Tags: java, android

I am currently having a little problem with my application. It is a music player and is working perfectly, except for one annoyance. When I run my SongAdapter, it will load a lot of views with the songs that are present on the device. However, this is way too heavy to load on the Main Thread, therefore I tried running it in the background. However, this isn't fast enough.

Main question:
Is there any fast and reliable way to load the images into the views.

Here is the code of my SongAdapter.java:

```
public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //song list and layout
    private ArrayList<Song> songs;
    private LayoutInflater songInf;

    //constructor
    public SongAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Song> theSongs){
        songs=theSongs;
        songInf=LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return songs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //map to song layout
        RelativeLayout songLay = (RelativeLayout) songInf.inflate(R.layout.song_list_item, parent, false);

        //get title and artist views
        TextView songView               = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.titleListTextView);
        TextView artistView             = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.artistListTextView);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout   = (RelativeLayout)songLay.findViewById(R.id.layoutSelector);
        RoundedImageView albumView      = (RoundedImageView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.albumListImageView);

        //get song using position
        Song currSong = songs.get(position);

        //get title and artist strings
        albumView.setImageBitmap( getAlbumart(currSong, parent.getContext()) );
        songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
        artistView.setText(currSong.getArtist());

        relativeLayout.setTag( currSong.getID());

        return songLay;
    }

    public Bitmap getAlbumart(Song currentSong, Context context ) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.album_default);

        long albumId = (long) currentSong.getAlbumId();

        try {
            final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumId);

            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

            if (pfd != null) {
                FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Var log", "Error:" + e);
        }
        return bm;
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try Picasso library https://github.com/square/picasso. I hope ideal solution for your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this way I can't generate the bitmap with getAlbumart() on the spot.

Comment: I would also give Picasso a try. Maybe you could do your album art stuff with a custom transformation?

Comment: @BartKoppelmans consider using View recycling? it will also help

Comment: Picasso works, however, in combination with my listview, it starts loading the images when I scroll. This way the application crashes whenever I scroll too much.

Comment: @BartKoppelmans that's why you need view recycle to avoid such behavior on huge data in Lists

Comment: Could you explain some more on View Recycling? Do you perhaps have some links?

Comment: @BartKoppelmans i have posted an answer describing recycle views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aside of using Picasso or any other library to load bitmaps.
below is a code same to recycle views, just replace the `setImageBitmap()` with the one you are usign now (Picasso or whatever)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHodler holder = null;

    if(convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHodler();
        convertView = songInf.inflate(R.layout.song_list_item, parent, false);
        holder.songView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleListTextView);
        holder.artistView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.artistListTextView);
        holder.albumView = (RoundedImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.albumListImageView);
        holder.relativeLayout   = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutSelector);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder =(ViewHodler) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //get song using position
    Song currSong = songs.get(position);

    //get title and artist strings
    holder.albumView.setImageBitmap( getAlbumart(currSong, parent.getContext()) ); // replace getAlbumart() with the new way you are using
    holder.songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
    holder.artistView.setText(currSong.getArtist());

    holder.relativeLayout.setTag( currSong.getID());

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHodler{
    TextView songView;
    TextView artistView;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    RoundedImageView albumView;
}
```

**PS:** getting `RelativeLayout` i mean this `R.id.layoutSelector`
if it's a big view it will load more memory.

Comment: It gives an error at the 'else' part. It says that a viewholder is required and a object is given.

Comment: add (ViewHodler) after the =, i will edit the question

Comment: It works now, however it still crashes whenever I scroll through the listview

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vHzS81xt   A link to my complete logcat file, it says out of memory.

Comment: @BartKoppelmans it does have error: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at com.bartkoppelmans.wavelength.SongAdapter.getAlbumart(SongAdapter.java:100)`

Comment: I saw that, I posted that. But how can I solve that?

Comment: @BartKoppelmans from the error i can see you are still loading bitmap without Picasso or other libraries?

Comment: Nope, I am loading the image with Picasso

Comment: the error shows trace from adapter class to BitMapDescriptor , nothing else ... can you post how do are you loading image now?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured a way to reduce the memory usage and everything is pretty much working as it should. Thank you very much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) aims to provide a powerful, flexible and highly customizable instrument for image loading, caching and displaying. It provides a lot of configuration options and good control over the image loading and caching process.

It works for me, hope it will solve your problem.